# Java libgdx: Loading of assets, memory usage

Tags: java, libgdx

We are building java war 2 pc game. (2d, turn based, the maps are made up of hexes)

And we have problem with memory.

Our resources are about 850mb(images 750, thousands of small images).
This is development phase, so it will be less when we delete some unused data, compress etc.

But when we load all of that resources we are spending like 4gb of RAM.

We are using assetmanger and load everything in it.

But, the main problem is with terrains, because every scenario is using almost all terrains (except sea/lake etc.)

TextureAtlases are not used for terrains.

I guess it's a problem with:
"being forced to have textures of a size with a power of two (POT)".
I will try to fix this with TextureAtlas.

We recently added commanders to the game. And it seems that theirs portraits(80mb) consume like 700mb of RAM when they are loaded (using assetManeger [assetManeger.load("path_name", Texture.class);]

Which are the best practices in these situations, when is loaded something that all the time is used...

Any advice will be helpfull.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough info to help. Is this 2D or 3D? Are the terrain textures tiling? How is the POT requirement hurting you? Are you not using TextureAtlases at all?

Comment: 2D, strategic game, turn based, hex oriented.
so there are a lot of small pictures for terrains. (mountains, 
different kind of grass, roads, rivers, rails...).

And we don't use TextureAtlases... I am new to project and I need to fix this, and i was wrong when i said that problem is with units... That is done good we load only necesesery ones
and dispose them when we don't need them anymore.

My question is whether it's possible that terrains(150mb) consume like 1.5gb of memory when they are loaded using only asset manager. [assetManager.load("PATH_NAME", Texture.class);]

Comment: @Tenfour04 i forgot to tag you. Thank you for your interest...

Comment: Are you using too large images? I mean if you create a commander portrait that is `2000 * 2000` pixels and you only ever draw it on a  `400 x 400` area you are wasting a lot of memory. Also, do you really need all assets all the time? You can dispose your assets and load them back in whenever you want using the `AssetManager`.

Comment: @madmenyo hi guys, is there a tool to show me on what memory is wasted... would be great if I can see how much memory consume every resource... i suppose that the biggest part of this 4gb took VRAM..for now, i measure, adding comments (on part of code which load particular resources (terrains/commanders etc.) and looking at memory in Task Manager

Comment: @Tenfour04 question above :)

Comment: A texture takes up 4 bytes per pixel regardless of the original (compressed) image size. I don't think there is a best practices here. For your specific game, determine how much ram usage is acceptable to you vs time spent on loading screens.

Answer (score 0):

Using AssetManager instead of constructing Textures directly has no effect on how much memory something takes up when loaded.

Textures take up *a lot* more memory than source images if you are using PNG or JPG because they are uncompressed when loaded in memory. You can precompress images as ETC1 and they will stay compressed when loaded (and give a performance boost) but there are drawbacks, such as lack of alpha transprency. [Read here.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-Compression)

TextureAtlases will save some memory by reducing the total number of textures and wasted space in those textures. They can also make a big improvement in performance if used sensibly. There won't be much improvement if you are drawing the sprites in an order that frequently jumps between the different texture pages of atlas(es). And since you're concerned about total memory use, you need to organize them such that you can continue to unload what a stage is not using. The entire Atlas is either loaded or not so you would need to put assets that are distinct to separate stages into separate atlases.